# How can I bind radiobutton's checked property inside DataTemplate?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

This is my DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateThemes">
            <Grid Width="160" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28.3336664835612"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="161"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbThemeName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Text="{Binding ThemeName}" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe UI" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
                <Image Margin="0" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Path=ThemePicName, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" Grid.Row="3" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ThemeDescription}" FontSize="14.667" FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                           d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Apply" Margin="-10,0,0,0" 
                             d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The IsChecked property of RadioButton depends on `Theme` property which is available in my ViewModel. Initially I thought I will create a Converter that will pass the current row (datatemplate current DataContext)'s ThemeId and ViewModel's Theme (which is the selected  Theme)'s ThemeId property and if they both match I would check the radiobutton. But ConverterParameter cannot take Binding expression as it is not a DependencyProperty. So how do I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: since you can get the theme id and the selected theme id. why not creating a boolean property in your viewmodel and check if they match from there?

Comment: If the ThemeId and Theme properties are in the same view model - pass entire view model. If it is something more complex - I would use binding to the IsSelected property of ListBox, it is easier to bind to the SelectedItem property.

Comment: @Xin:- Don't know why didn't that strike me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a multi binding solution.  I have previously implemented the solution described here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/

You could then have a converter that accepts the two required parameters.